# C# Public IP Client/Server

Tags: c#, sockets, ipv4

For study purpose I've developed an async server/client application working on my local network. But now I want to make it able to connect to my public ip instead, so my server can be accessible from anywhere.

Here is relevant parts of Server Code, it seems to be working just fine:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            AsyncServer server = new AsyncServer(60101);
            server.RunAsync();
            Console.Read();
    }

public class AsyncServer
{
    private IPAddress ipAddress;
    private int port;

    public AsyncServer(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        this.ipAddress = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < ipHostInfo.AddressList.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ipHostInfo.AddressList[i].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                this.ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (this.ipAddress == null)
            throw new Exception("No IPv4 address for server.");
    }

    public async void RunAsync()
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(this.ipAddress, this.port);
        tcpListener.Start();
```

Here is relevant parts of Client Code. Here is where it fails to connect.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            AsyncClient client = new AsyncClient("MyPublicIP", 60101);
            client.ConnectAsync().Wait();
            Console.Read();
    }
}

public class AsyncClient
{
    private IPAddress ipAddress;
    private int port;

    public AsyncClient(string ip, int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
        IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out ipAddress);
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync()
    {
        int attempts = 0;
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        while (!client.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                attempts++;
                client.Connect(this.ipAddress, this.port);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                await ProcessAssync(client);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Attempts: {0}", attempts);
```

I've already made port forwarding on my router to my local server IP "192.168.254.1" to the used port "60101", but nothing changes, he just keeps there trying for a while then fails the connection.

Comment: He wont be connecting to 192.168.254.1 .. he needs your internet IP address thats your local one

Comment: Yes, 192.168.254.1 is my local IP, but this is the one I need for the server right? So the server listens to everything send to this IP on the given port, just like I set on port forwarding. Then on client I am not trying to connect to it, it's trying to connect to my public IP. Isn't this how it should be?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct. So the problem may be ISP filtering or forward not working or some other thing.

Comment: Check that your firewalls are configured to let the communication pass...

Comment: There's a lot of irrelevant code in your question. Read [ask] and create a [mcve]. You're probably binding to the wrong address. You definitely can't bind to your public IP address, as that's assigned to your router, not your PC (assuming your typical household router).

Comment: I edited the post, should look better now. How would I bind the wrong address, it should be clear on the code that it is not possible. I use my public IP that I get on sites like whatsmyip.org only on the client, to try to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want/need to limit the Server to listen only on one interface?

When you start the TcpListener only with the Port number but without the IP address, the TcpListener will listen on all interfaces. With your code, the TcpListener will onyl listen on the first interface with an IPv4 IP address. But this could be an interface not available to your router (e.g. an internal interface provided by a virtualization host).

I would change the server code to something like this:

```
public class AsyncServer
{
    private int port;

    public AsyncServer(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public async void RunAsync()
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, this.port);
        tcpListener.Start();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try http://www.whatsmyip.org/ and parse that IP. For the server maybe would be better use IPAddress.Any

Comment: In general, when behind NAT (as is very common) your public IP is assigned to your modem/router, not your PC.